# ActiveRecord::Base.connected? returns true even if DB is down

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database-connection, rails-activerecord

Once a connection has been established to the DB, calling `ActiveRecord::Base.connected?` returns true even if DB is down. This can be reproduced by spinning up a rails app and a database container, then killing the DB container once the app has booted and running `rails console` and checking the value of `ActiveRecord::Base.connected?`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`ActiveRecord::Base.connected?` simply tells you that [a connection has already been opened](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/ConnectionPool.html#method-i-connected-3F). It may not necessarily still be active.

To check whether the connection is currently active, call `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.active?`. This will actually ping the DB server.